# Изменить высоту ячейки таблицы

Tags: c#, wpf, fastreport

Как сделать, чтобы высота ячейки автоматически увеличивалась в зависимости от размера контента внутри неё?

В руководстве есть такая штука как AutoSize, только у меня её почему-то нет. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ это сделать без AutoSize? У меня фастрепорт работает с C#, возможно ли каким-нибудь образом запрограммировать это в коде?

Я попробовал что-то типа этого:

```
namespace FastReport
{
    public class ReportScript
    {
        private void Table2_BeforePrint(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Cell45.Text.Length > 24)
            {
              Cell45.Height *= 2;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Ничего не происходит, хотя когда я вместо высоты меняю цвет шрифта - работает.

Неплохо было бы хотя бы понять, как это в принципе делается.

Comment: тип проекта wpf или winforms ?

Comment: @Сергей проект wpf

Comment: покажите ваш код

Comment: @Gardes Кода собственно нет. Я просто из датасета надергал данных и всё. В коде пока пусто, так как для моего отчёта он не понадобился.

Comment: нужен кусок xaml разметки